# Add correct spacing to postcode (UK)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, postal-code

I've got the following to add spaces to a postcode:

```
function isValidPostcode(p) { 
var postcodeRegEx = /[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2} ?[0-9][A-Z]{2}/i; 
return postcodeRegEx.test(p); }

function formatPostcode(p) { 
if (isValidPostcode(p)) { 
    var postcodeRegEx = /(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9][A-Z]{2}$)/i; 
    return p.replace(postcodeRegEx,"$1 $2"); 
} else {
    return p;
}}
```

It checks the postcode and adds a space.  It works for postcodes with SA143TG and adds a space to make SA14 3TQ, but with SA13TQ it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't work? How should the output for SA13TQ look like? Should it be SA13 TQ?

Comment: [It looks working](https://regex101.com/r/De8IgN/1).

Comment: It should come out as SA1 3TQ

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line

```
var postcodeRegEx = /(^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9][A-Z]{2}$)/i;
```

try this

```
var postcodeRegEx = /([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2})([0-9][A-Z]{2})/i;
```